# Using HashMap object in Dynamic Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

```
    public void showApplicantCountVsJobBoardsSimpleReport(Collection<ApplicantCountVsJobBoardsDTO> applicantCountVsJobBoardsList,HttpServletRequest request) throws ColumnBuilderException,ClassNotFoundException, JRException {        
            initStyles();  
            FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
            setTitleProperties(drb,"Job Board by Company and Job Title");   
            reportTitle = "Job-Board-by-Company-and-Job-Title";       
            DynamicReport dr = createApplicantCountVsJobBoardsSimpleReport(drb, applicantCountVsJobBoardsList); 
            jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(applicantCountVsJobBoardsList));
            request.getSession().setAttribute("JasperPrintObject", jp);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("ReportName", reportTitle);
            displayReport(request, 0);     
        }   

        private DynamicReport createApplicantCountVsJobBoardsSimpleReport(FastReportBuilder drb, Collection<ApplicantCountVsJobBoardsDTO> applicantCountVsJobBoardsList) {
            AbstractColumn columnCompanyName = setStringColumnProperties("companyName","Company Name",100);
            drb.addColumn(columnCompanyName);

            AbstractColumn columnJobTitle = setStringColumnProperties("jobName","Job Title",200);       
            drb.addColumn(columnJobTitle);      

            AbstractColumn columnTotal = setStringColumnProperties("totalApplicantForJob","Total",100);
            drb.addColumn(columnTotal);     

            return drb.build();
        }


public class ApplicantCountVsJobBoardsDTO {

    private String companyName;
    private String jobName;
    private Integer totalApplicantForJob;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> jobBoard;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }
    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }   
    public Integer getTotalApplicantForJob() {
        return totalApplicantForJob;
    }
    public void setTotalApplicantForJob(Integer totalApplicantForJob) {
        this.totalApplicantForJob = totalApplicantForJob;
    }
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getJobBoard() {
        return jobBoard;
    }
    public void setJobBoard(HashMap<String, Integer> jobBoard) {
        this.jobBoard = jobBoard;
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea to add the jobBoard items to the report.. Each item in the jobBoard object will be a column in my report. Please help me. I am new to Jasper. :(

I am using `net.sf.jasperreports` and `ar.com.fdvs.dj` jars

Comment: Do you have a specific need to create the report template through code? You can use iReport to create your report template and use the compiled .jasper file to populate the report with the data and export it.

Comment: no. I need to do like this :(

Comment: @1355 Did you check any samples?

Comment: I tried with subreport. But I cant make it to success..

Comment: please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632750/subreport-in-jasper-using-java

Answer (score 0):

In this Case you will have to use subreport feature of ireport tool in which you pass hashmap as a datasource and ther in that report you decide layout and design of your report.

Comment: could you please give me the code flow also. I also saw sub report creations. Tried. but not working. :(

Comment: you have to add jobBoard field and set its datatype as HashMap.
Then you pass this in subreport as a datasource. Hope you are using iReport tool to set the layout of your report.
I can help you futher but I am not getting you code.If you could give me your email ID I will forward you a sample code which uses subreport